# JQuery not find element which JavaScript find. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code:

```
if (!jQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).hasClass('invisible'))
    JQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).addClass('invisible');
```

throws exception: "Microsoft JScript - runtime error: Expected an object." (I hope that it is correct translation, because I have this message localized to my language)

but this code:

```
if (!jQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).hasClass('invisible'))
    document.getElementById('item_SwitchBoard' + index).className = 'invisible';
```

works without problem.

Why?

I don't understant it. I supposed that it should be same (or analogic) thing. And how is possible that

```
if (!jQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).hasClass('invisible'))
```

works, but practicly same function:

```
JQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).addClass('invisible');
```

say to me that "Expected an object.". This object has been taken by hell during milisecond or what?

I use getElementById if it works, but I interested why JQuery not works correctly in all cases. Any ideas?

It is 1.4.2 version of JQuery.

Comment: Unfortunately JavaScript is case sensitive... even jQuery is not immune. :)

Answer (score 9):

Could it be the capital J in JQuery?
jQuery refers to an object while JQuery does not refer to an object.

Comment: oh lord, where are my eyes :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!jQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).hasClass('invisible'))
    JQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).addClass('invisible');
```

Your second line has `JQuery` when it should be `jQuery`

```
if (!jQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).hasClass('invisible'))
    jQuery('#item_SwitchBoard' + index).addClass('invisible');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because capitalization is important. You need to use `jQuery`, not `JQuery`.